# In Ruby, what's a good way to specify a series of probabilities and then define a factory that returns a result based on them?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am trying to come up with a simple implementation of a function that takes a series of probabilities and corresponding outcomes, and then lets me call it to get a random outcome consistent with the probabilities.

In this case, users will be able to enter the probabilities to as fine a level of precision as they want:

```
  oracle = Oracle.new
  oracle << Scenario.new(probability: 0.0001, result: 1)
  oracle << Scenario.new(probability: 0.01, result: 2)
  oracle << Scenario.new(probability: 0.1, result: 3)
  oracle << Scenario.new(probability: nil, result: 4) #oracle will fill to 100%

  result = oracle.result
```

With fixed precision, I could manipulate the numbers and use rand(), but even that is a bit janky/verbose.

Is there a clever way to define #result?

Comment: So you're building a sequence of intervals like `[0, 0.0001)`, `[0.0001, 0.0101)`, `[0.0101, 0.1101)`, and `[0.1101, 1.0]` by specifying their lengths?

Comment: You might consider using Ruby's `Rational` class instead of `Float`, to avoid precision issues when operating on probabilities.

Comment: @muistooshort That's the CDF, which would be valid but would require more work for calculating joint or conditional probabilities.

Comment: *"as fine a level of precision as they want"* ... provided they don't exceed the precision of the random number generator. In fact, they probably want to stay well short of the precision of the random number generator.

Comment: Your question currently focuses on specifying the probabilities, but I'm not sure I'm understanding your use case.  Are you asking how to randomly generate results with the associated probabilities?  If so, see https://rubygems.org/gems/aliastable

Comment: @pjs But it has the advantage of being easy to understand and sufficient if you're just rolling the dice rather than doing "real" stats work.